# Scanner input string without spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I was wondering how I can do this.

I was told to use `kb.nextLine()` instead of `kb.next()` , but that just results in the input being skipped when I run the program.

```
String address;
student.setAddress(address = kb.nextLine());
```

I was then told to do this to fix it:

```
student.SetAddress(String address = kb.nextLine());
```

but I get an error:
`String cannot be resolved into a variable" "Syntax error on token "address"`

Comment: Can you show more of your code? The first line you posted should work, but without the context, it's hard to say where the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second example is wrong. Your first example looks okay. But not great. I assume you've been using something like `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()`. They leave a trailing new line, so you need to consume it.

```
kb.nextLine(); // <-- consume empty trailing line.
String address; 
student.setAddress(address = kb.nextLine()); //<-- reads line.
```

If you don't need a local copy of address,

```
kb.nextLine(); // <-- consume empty trailing line.
student.setAddress(kb.nextLine()); //<-- reads line.
```

As [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) Javadoc says,

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.